# Laravel - Maatwebsite displayed successful but nothing was imported into the table

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 and Maatwebsite-3.1 package, I have this code:

```
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Country;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsErrors;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnError;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsFailures;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsEmptyRows;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure;
use Throwable;

class CountryImport implements
    ToModel,
    WithValidation,
    WithHeadingRow,
    SkipsOnError,
    SkipsOnFailure,
    WithBatchInserts
{
    private $rows = 0;    // variable to count rows
    use Importable, SkipsErrors, SkipsFailures;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Country([
            'name'                              => $row[0],
            'nationality'                       => $row[1],
            'created_at'                        => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'created_by'                        => Auth::user()->id,
        ]);
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public function getRowCount(): int
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }

    public function customValidationAttributes()
    {
        return [
            '0'     => 'Country',
            '1'     => 'Nationality',
        ];
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            '*.0' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:100',
                Rule::unique('countries', 'name')
            ],
            '*.1' => [
                'nullable',
                'string',
                'max:50',
                Rule::unique('countries', 'nationality')
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }

    public function onFailure(Failure ...$failures)
    {
        // Handle the failures how you'd like.
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function importCountry(Request $request)
{
   DB::beginTransaction();
   $user = Auth::user()->id;
   $userEmail = Auth::user()->email;
try {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'document' => 'file|mimes:xlsx|max:10000',
    ]);
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->error($validator->errors(), 401);
    } else {
        $check = User::where('id', $user)->pluck('id');
        if($check[0] !== null || $check[0] !== undefined) {

            $file = $request->file('document');
            $file->move(public_path('storage/file_imports/location_imports'), $file->getClientOriginalName());
            Excel::import(new CountryImport, public_path('storage/file_imports/location_imports/' . $file->getClientOriginalName() ));
            DB::commit();
            return $this->success('Nationalities Successfully Imported.', [
                'file'         => $file
            ]);
        } else {
            return $this->error('Not allowed', 401);
        }
    }
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error($e);
        return $this->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

I am using Laravel as the API endpoint and Angular as the frontend.

It displays successful, and the Excel file found in storage/file_imports/location_imports as instructed.

But nothing was stored in the database without any error.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller code is not correct. You are doing wrong stuff about the `DB Transaction`... See that, if you have any validation error, you are never reverting back or doing anything with the transaction itself...

Try this code:

```php
public function importCountry(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'document' => 'file|mimes:xlsx|max:10000',
    ]);

    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $file = $request->file('document');
        $file->move(
            public_path('storage/file_imports/location_imports'),
            $file->getClientOriginalName()
        );

        Excel::import(
            new CountryImport,
            public_path('storage/file_imports/location_imports/' . $file->getClientOriginalName())
        );

        DB::commit();
    } catch(\Throwable $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error($e);
        
        return $this->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }

    return $this->success('Nationalities Successfully Imported.', compact('file'));
}
```

Please, see how I removed a lot of code:

- I have updated your validation, I know you were returning `401`, but that is not correct, as you are having a validation error (`422` error). If you still need `401` (that is `unauthorized`) you have to add your code again.
- I have updated your `if` check, as it makes no sense to get the `user` and check if it is not `null` or `undefined` (`undefined` does not even exist in PHP, that should be a PHP error). It makes no sense, because you are using `Auth::user()->id` or `Auth::id()` (both are the same), and you will always get a user back, so why go to the database and get it again ? You already have it...

  - If you want to check if the user is logged in or similar, you have to add a middleware to the route... If you are in this part of the controller, it means that the previous layer "authorized" the entry to it, so it is the route's middleware responsibility to allow or not, not the controller in this case.
  - And if you want to still do that in the controller, simply do `->first()` instead of `->pluck('id')` and check if the variable is `null` or not.
- I updated your `catch` exception, try to stick to `Throwable` as it is more correct. You can google more about it.

Comment: When I updated the code as you sent, still the same thing. Then as I tested on POSTMAN, I got this error:       lError: Call to a member function move() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: So, you are not getting a file, are you sure you are sending it correctly with Postman ?

Comment: I don't know why POSTMAN is doing that. But , if I import it from the frontend (Angular) into the backend (Laravel), the excel file gets to the storage public_path('storage/file_imports/location_imports'), which shows I am sending the file. Then from the storage, I need to now import and save it into the DB. And that's where the problem lies.

Comment: What is the problem on storing it ? I have never stored a file in a database, but I think the column should be BLOB or something like that.

Comment: as I dd(public_path('storage/file_imports/location_imports/' . $file->getClientOriginalName() ));   I got this:    "C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\public\storage/file_imports/location_imports/list.xlsx"   Some back stroke and some the other way. Could that have been the problem?

Comment: Thanks so much. Just needed to change row[0] and others to row['name'] and so on